# How do I set profile image as first letters of first and last name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, reactjs

Basically, i'm working on user registration system. which i'm doing front-end using ReactJS. for registered users there is an option to add images for their profiles. **when there is no images for the profiles, profile image should be contain the first letter from the first and second name for the profile picture** like google plus do.

**please find the sample image below.**

[image]

Looking forward a way to do this.. better if there are inbuilt plugin or library to do this.

Comment: Create circle, input text, done... What have you tried? This is pretty straight forward...

Comment: thanks for the reply mate. currently i'm doing that way :D,  In google +, time to time they change the background colors also.

Comment: If you're already doing that... what is is the problem then?

Comment: Is that the way or are there any other inbuilt plugins for that ?

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Using an image for the circle, pure CSS.. I don't know if there are any plugins for this, but if you are looking for one I want to direct you to the SO help section. The help section explains that this website should not be used for looking for libraries or plugins.

Comment: Much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: This is too easy to look for an external plugin. Just use css.

Comment: Love the answers, missing the randomization of the bg colors

Comment: perhaps helpful to not have to code all yourself : https://ui-avatars.com/ ( comes with a github page)

Comment: What if the user has an image, how would we know whether the user has an image or not ? Could somebody also point on how it can be figured out  whether the user has an image if not then the initials. Just like google/gmail

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I have assumed that you have access to the first name and last name. Using that, I have written this code which will take the first letter from First name and last name and apply to your profile image.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var firstName = $('#firstName').text();
  var lastName = $('#lastName').text();
  var intials = $('#firstName').text().charAt(0) + $('#lastName').text().charAt(0);
  var profileImage = $('#profileImage').text(intials);
});
```

```css
#profileImage {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #512DA8;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="firstName">Kalpesh</span>
<span id="lastName">Singh</span>
<div id="profileImage"></div>
```

Comment: I beat you by 19 sec. :D Code pretty much the same except I don't use JQuery.

Comment: that 19 sec. was invested in writing jQuery :p

Answer (score 23):

UI Avatars has a simple-to-use API with no limiting or login. No usage tracking and no information is stored. The final images are cached, but nothing else. Just write name or surname, or both.

**Generate a avatar with default settings, for user "John Doe".** 
https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=John+Doe

**Generate a blue avatar** 
https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff

**Generate a random background avatar.**
https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29789348)

Comment: This is a 3rd party service trusted by many big brands. The links are used only for reference to understand how to use them. More in-depth documentation is available on their website.

Answer (score 12):

The css option added in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5x2n1w5c/2)

- You just create a `div` inside `div`.
- Put the inner one in the complete center with `line-height` the same
  as container's size and `text-align: center`.

You can also have the text set by Javascript if needed. 
**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="name">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #333;
}
#name {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

**Optional Javascript**

```
  var name = "Adam";
  var lastname = "Sandler";
  var initials = name.charAt(0)+""+lastname.charAt(0);
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = initials;
```

Answer (score 11):

It could be written as a one-liner.

```
fullName.split(' ').map(name => name[0]).join('').toUpperCase()
```

**Runnable snippet:**

```js
const fullName = document.getElementById('fullName').textContent;
const intials = fullName.split(' ').map(name => name[0]).join('').toUpperCase();
document.getElementById('profileImage').innerHTML = intials;
```

```css
#profileImage {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #004D3C;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="profileImage"></div>
<span id="fullName">Penny Liu</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution takes care of user names with names having more than 2 words. I used regex to extract first letters of space separated name components.

```
    var matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g);
    var acronym = matches.join('');
    document.getElementById("name_acronym").innerHTML = acronym;
```

Call this function containing this from your HTML code and "name_acronym" is the id for the profile picture text.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of getting first character of a string. 
And even some times you might get **$** as undefined when your using

```
var firstName = $('#firstName').text();
```

try this ...

```
var firstName = "Jhon";
var initial = firstName.charAt(0);
console.log('--------', initial);
```

by this you should get "J" as output

Answer (score 0):

outside of return:

```
 var intials;
 var fullName = "Mahendren Manoharan"
 intials = fullName.split(' ').map(name =>name[0]).join('').toUpperCase();
 console.log('intials',intials); - check here your output
```

My output - MM

first make a one condition based on your response. Im using based on my response

inside of return:

```
{profileLogo != undefined || profileLogo != "" ? (
                <View
                // source={require("../../assets/images/Johnwick.jpg")}
                style={styles.profileImage}
              >
                <Text style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',color:'white'}}>{intials}</Text>

                </View>
                
              
              ) : (
                <Image
                  source={require("../../assets/images/Johnwick.jpg")}
                  style={styles.profileImage}
                />
              )}
```

that's all... enjoy your coding...

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = await User.create({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    contactNumber,
    password: hashedPassword,
    accountType,
    additionalDetails: profileDetails._id,
    image: "https://api.dicebear.com/5.x/initials/svg?seed=${firstname} ${lastName}",

  })
```